# How can I restore grub for Fedora 17?

Tags: fedora, grub2

I have mistakenly deleted all the grub entries while customizing grub using "Grub Customizer". Now whenever Im trying to boot into Fedora Linux a black screen is coming up only with "grub>" prompt.

How can I fix this problem ? I have other two OSs installed side-by-side.
Fedora is on "sda3"

Answer (score 3):

Luckily the [Fedora Wiki](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/17/html/Installation_Guide/ap-rescuemode.html#s2-rescuemode-boot-reinstall-bootloader) covers this topic! Seems you can just reinstall GRUB very easily, just using a live CD.

1. Boot the system from an installation boot medium. (live CD/USB)
2. Type linux rescue at the installation boot prompt to enter the rescue environment.
3. Type chroot /mnt/sysimage to mount the root partition.
4. Type /sbin/grub-install bootpart to reinstall the GRUB boot loader, where bootpart is the boot partition (typically, /dev/sda). (in your case, sda3 perhaps)
5. Review the /etc/grub.d/10_linux file, as additional entries may be needed in the /etc/grub.d/40_custom for GRUB to control additional operating systems.
6. Reboot the system.

These instructions are straight from the Wiki.

Answer (score 0):

No need to change as sda3; use /dev/sda. Then use the command

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```