# Can I repair the bootloader for Fedora 17 from Ubuntu 12?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, grub

I don't have access to the install media for Fedora right now. Can I restore boot loader for Fedora from Ubuntu 12?

- [How can I restore grub for Fedora 17?](https://superuser.com/questions/469249/how-can-i-restore-grub-for-fedora-17)

Comment: Why do you think you need to restore the boot loader?  What error are you getting?

Comment: I could not boot into fedora. (Fatal error occurred... blah blah blah.. ! and Kernel Panic"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. What I did is :

1. First I have copied the grub.cfg from my Ubuntu installation and replace that with Fedoras grub.cfg.
2. After that I have changed some entries in grub.cfg, like I have replaced the UUID, Name of the initrd file and msdos9 to msdos3.
3. After that rebooted and got access to Fedora.
4. After that used Grub Customzer to re-write grub entries for fedora.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/17/html/Installation_Guide/ap-rescuemode.html#s2-rescuemode-boot-reinstall-bootloader):

1. Boot your Ubuntu.
2. Open a terminal and mount the Fedora partition: `sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/fedora` (where sdXY is the partition where you have Fedora installed). Most likely, X will be `a` (for the first hard drive installed in your system).
3. Just for good measure, mount `/dev` and `/proc` there: `sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/fedora/dev` and `sudo  mount -o bind /proc /mnt/fedora/proc`. I don't know if this is still needed but it won't hurt.
4. `chroot` into it: `sudo  chroot /mnt/fedora`. This will give you access to your Fedora install.
5. Then, run `/sbin/grub-install /dev/sdX`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Which part do you want me to elaborate on?

Comment: Please write the whole steps like (1,2,3...). If possible explain things in non technical terms.

Comment: @CuriousApprentice edited the answer, try now.

Comment: When Im trying to mount,(mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/fedora it says the path is invalid.

Comment: Sudo does not work as you are saying. I needed to use su instead of sudo to be root as a live user.

Comment: /sbin/grub-install says command not found.

Comment: Did you create the `/mnt/fedora` directory before mounting?

Comment: nope ! do needed to create that ?!

Comment: mkdir /mnt/fedora ? like this ?

Comment: @CuriousApprentice yes.

Comment: /sbin/grub-install /dev/sdX not working. It says no file or such directory.

Comment: tried using grub2-install /dev/sda3 but it says "/usr/sbin/grub2-bios-setup: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
"

Comment: Replace the `X` by `a`.